# How to get a content of file on the Internet?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios

How to get a content of file on the Internet? For example, I want to get to NSString a content of rss feed from http://news.tut.by/rss/index.rss . How can I do it? I want to use only iOS SDK classes: NSURLConnection, NSURLRequest etc.
P.S. I saw such class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface RssDownloader : NSObject {
 NSURLConnection * conn;
 NSMutableData * receivedData;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection * conn;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData * receivedData;

- (void)downloadUrlContent : (NSURL *)url;
@end




@implementation RssDownloader

@synthesize receivedData, conn;

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
 [receivedData release];
 receivedData = nil;
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
 [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
 [connection release];
 [receivedData release];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
 [connection release];
 [receivedData release];
}

- (void) downloadUrlContent:(NSURL *)url {
 NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                  timeoutInterval:60.0];
 conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
 if (conn) {
  receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
 }
}

- (void)dealloc {
 [conn release];
 [receivedData release];
}
@end
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing everything correctly right up until the connection finishes loading.  There you are releasing the data before you do anything with it.  On your delegate class, create an `NSString` variable (you probably already have this).  Then, inside `connectionDidFinishLoading`, convert it to a string before releasing it:

```
if(receivedData != nil){
   NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[receivedData bytes]];
   [receivedData release];
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Even after this changes I can't recieve a content of file. I do it so http://pastie.org/1514999

Comment: The code you linked to only invokes the URL.  Did you modify the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method?

Comment: Yeah, I did it. But debugger "said" me that this method even doesn't perform(I set breakpoint at this function).

Answer (score 1):

change

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
   [receivedData release];
   receivedData = nil;
}
```

to

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
}
```

just because the function didReceiveResponse will be called before connectionDidFinishLoading

Comment: It would be be better if you had explained what was the problem and why your solution fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem when using:

```
if(receivedData != nil){
   NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[receivedData bytes]];
   [receivedData release];
}
```

The problem was a corrupted string from my .json file.
I'm using:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

There are a quick mode to read a remote file:

```
NSString *file = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:<your url here>] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

It is a quick mode, but you don't have any control about server's response.